# Are AUCTeX forward search and inverse search meant to work with C-c C-r and C-c C-b too?

Tags: emacs, auctex, forward-inverse-search

Background:

<kbd>C-c C-r</kbd> is like <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> except it's for compiling & viewing just a fixed portion (specified by the user) of a TeX buffer.

<kbd>C-c C-b</kbd> is like <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> except it's for compiling & viewing just the current TeX file (rather than the `TeX-master` file) in a multi-file document.

Is source correlate mode supposed to work with <kbd>C-c C-r</kbd> and <kbd>C-c C-b</kbd> as well? It doesn't seem to work with them under my configuration, but I don't know if it's my configuration or if it's lack of support.

If no, is there a hack or a workaround?

Comment: Inverse/forward searches work out-of-the-box (if enabled, of course) between the PDF and the `_region_.tex` file, not the original source file.

Comment: Then I guess the answer is no for now, although it would be nice to have it work with at least C-c C-b.

Comment: Yes, the answer is "no".  I don't think it would be an easy task, one needs to define a map between the `_region_.tex` and the original source file.